# Convert date format of string to datetime MM/dd/yyyy when system date formate is dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, wpf

I need convert the date of string format 'MM/dd/yyyy' to datetime format 'MM/dd/yyyy' when the system date format is 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

Comment: Something to learn than asking for codes - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also this article about custom format strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` stores a date as a numerical value, not as a string. So asking for a `DateTime` *type of format 'MM/dd/yyyy'* doesn't make much sense. If you are displaying the date in a WPF control, it will default to *displaying* a string that conforms to the system date format. But that is just a *display string* that you can manipulate using the format strings alluded to in the links above. Using @Sajeetharan's code will create a `DateTime` struct with the correct value internally. How you display it is up to you and your string formatting choices.

The same goes for dates stored in a database column of type 'datetime'. The value is stored numerically. Your query editor will *display* the value likely in the same format as your system settings. If the date is stored as a string, then again, @Sajeetharan's code is the correct way to convert the database string into a `DateTime` struct.

Answer (score 1):

use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("05/02/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for your update.I tried this but the result is in string i need in DateTime type since my database value is in Datetime in "MM/dd/yyyy" format.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
string dateString="05/02/2014";
DateTime txtmyDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy",     
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for your update. I tried this but the final output date format is same as the system's current date format.I need the result in DateTime type of format 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

Comment: Using `DateTime.ParseExact` should convert your date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format. What is the final output stored in `txtmydate` ?

Comment: When my system date format is 'dd/MM/yyyy' then value stored in txtmydate is 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
string dateString="05/02/2014";
DateTime txtmyDate =convert.toDateTime(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("05/02/2014","MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation around your code, rather than just the code itself.